# Deriving 2 keys using HKDF

Tags: key-derivation, hkdf

I have an encryption scheme that uses a 256-bit master key, from which 2 separate keys (one for AES-256-CTR encryption and one for a HMAC-SHA256) are derived using HKDF. However, I'm not sure exactly how to utilize HKDF without screwing it up, so straight to my concerns:

1. Is it safe to just use SHA-512 as the hashing algorithm to get a 512-bit output and split it in 2?
2. I know that using salt is not mandatory, but does using it actually improve security?
3. I know this might be a dumb idea, but still ... can the salt be the IV used for encryption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. You can either use `HKDF-expand` twice with different `info` values, or once with a longer output length.
2. Depends. If your 256-bit master key is generated using a secure RNG, a salt is unnecessary. OTOH, if it's derived from something with less entropy, like a password, having unique salts would ensure uniqueness of derived keys even if the master keys happened to match for two users or sessions.
3. Probably not a good idea, but whether it's secure depends on how the IV is chosen.

   HKDF assumes that the salt is not attacker-chosen. If an attacker can influence the IV, then that's a definite no. OTOH, if the IV known to be completely independent of the key, it *should* be secure, since CTR doesn't place any requirements on the IV beyond uniqueness.

   Still, if you can just create another random number to use as a salt, it's simpler to do that. And if you can't be sure the salt isn't attacker-controlled, it's better to leave it out altogether.

Comment: Great, thank you. After thinking about it again, I wouldn't be able to use the IV as salt anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Although the answer is already accepted, I'll add an answer with a different look on things.

> *1. Is it safe to just use SHA-512 as the hashing algorithm to get a 512-bit output and split it in 2?*

It's safe, but that's not what HKDF-expand should be used for. The idea of HKDF-expand is to call it twice, once for each key, using the `info` element to distinguish between the two (e.g. `info` could be an ASCII encoding of the key name). Note that HKDF should have a relatively short running time.

> *2. I know that using salt is not mandatory, but does using it actually improve security?*

Although it is not required, it is best to use a salt. So unless there is some important reason not to - such as the requirement for a deterministic protocol or the unavailability of a random number generator, please do so. It is relatively unusual for a KBKDF algorithm to have a salt parameter, but the authors seem to think it is important; see the quote underneath this answer.

> *3. I know this might be a dumb idea, but still ... can the salt be the IV used for encryption?*

You could, however I would urge you to independently generate it using HKDF-expand, see answer (1).

---

Quote for part #2 (see 3.1 of the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869)):

> We stress, however, that the use of salt adds significantly to the
> strength of HKDF, ensuring independence between different uses of the
> hash function, supporting "source-independent" extraction, and
> strengthening the analytical results that back the HKDF design.

Comment: Thanks for the further input. My goal was to achieve maximum performance by having just one `hkdf()` call and possibly using already existing data for salt if that would increase security. Unfortunately, by achieving my first goal, I can't practically do the latter.

Comment: HKDF is of course the latest/greatest method to do KBKDF calculations, but you may consider using [KDF1](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15673/security-of-kdf1-and-kdf2-hash-based-kdfs) instead. That will mean you are using a less secure KDF, but you would be using it in the way that is intended to be used. Using a NIST specified KDF in counter mode (NIST SP 800-108 if I'm not mistaken) using AES may also speed up your KDF, especially on systems that have AES instructions on the CPU.