# Session-specific Symmetric Key Derivation Using SHA256

Tags: symmetric, keys, key-derivation, sha-256

I was wondering if there were any security implications of deriving session keys from a symmetric key using SHA256 in the following manner: $Ks = SHA256(Nonce||K)$, where $Nonce$ is the session specific nonce and $K$ is the pre-shared symmetric key. And $Ks$ will be derived at both ends as mentioned.

As far as I am aware, length extension attacks are not applicable here as being able to append additional data to the input makes no difference. Would $Ks = HMAC(Nonce, K)$ be any different security-wise? What would be an advisable way of going about my requirement?

Comment: Closely related: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15673/security-of-kdf1-and-kdf2-hash-based-kdfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HMAC:** The [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) version is considered slightly more secure than [sha-256](/questions/tagged/sha-256), assuming it's also based on SHA-256, because the HMAC formulation folds in the key material with 2 rounds of hashing, making it harder to use a chosen plaintext attack on the digest.

**SHA-256:** SHA-256 should be relatively secure against chosen plaintext attacks, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

You can also achieve a higher level of assurance and forward security provided $K$ is not long-lived, but rather is chained to the immediately previous session.

For some stored value `D1`:

```
K2 = HMAC(Nonce,D1)     // session key
D2 = HMAC(Nonce,K2)     // stored material for a future session
authtoken = E(K2,Nonce) // auth token proving client derived K2 correctly
```

If you want to authenticate the server, you can also pass a token from server to client, thus proving the server knows `D1`.  Something like,

```
servtoken = E(K2,authtoken)   // proof server knows D1
```

Client checks `servtoken` before sending `authtoken`.  `D1` is discarded and replaced with `D2`. So you have bidirectional authentication and forward security.