# Composing hash functions

Tags: hash, implementation

Suppose there is a cryptographic hash function $H : \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb G$. Now, we want to define a hash function $H' : \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb G \times \mathbb G $.

My first idea is to define $H'$ in the following way:

$H'(x) = (H(x||'0'), H(x||'1'))$

Is $H'$ cryptographically secure? If not, can you propose a secure construction that uses $H$?

The motivation behind this question is that some crypto libraries (e.g., Charm) provide functions for hashing to groups (e.g., $H$), but in some cases you need custom hash functions (e.g., $H'$)

Comment: Two comments: 1) your construction looks very much like [KDF2](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15673/1172), which is probably secure. 2) you won't double your security using this construction (but I don't think you intended to do that). If $x$ is relatively small you could use any KDF, using $x$ as secret.

Comment: You might want to clarify what it needs to be secure *against*.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes "_your construction looks very much like KDF2, which is probably secure_". Do you mean "probably" or "provably"? Regarding the intended security notion, I wasn't targeting anything in particular... I guess the usual stuff (pre-image resistance, collision resistance, etc). I basically wanted to know if my original idea has some inherent problem, or if maybe there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: No, **probably** secure. Note that **I asked** the question about the security KDF1/2 constructs. Lookfor something based on HMAC such as HKDF for better proofs.