# Crypto lib that use files instead of passphrase

Tags: keys, symmetric, file-encryption

I would like to program an application to allow people to encrypt files **without** using a password or pass-phrase but an arbitrary long file.

I'm searching for a library that allows me to safely create a front-end.

Example: user 1 on PC1 encrypt the picture `selfie.png` (size 2 MB) using the key-file `ketfile.foo` (size 2 MB), then send  this file to user2 on PC2 that use `keyfile.foo` to decrypt `selfie.png`.
Of course I assume that the `keyfile.foo` was "securely" sent.

This idea come from the Vernam Cipher "Unbreakable" cipher.

Comment: You may simply read file content (as bytes-string or bits-string) and pass it to the encryptor as the **key**.

Comment: Good Point, but I'm asking myself if this solution is the most efficient or is practicable because some tools desn't read the pass-phrase from the command-line via parameter (they ask in an interactive way)

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I won't recommend a specific library for these, because this would be off-topic and the risk would be there that this gets outdated sooner than later (especially as soon as [CAESAR](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html) finishes).**

This is a very standard solution to the authentication problem although usually one does do both (e.g. passphrase *and* keyfile).

On the conceptual level any library exposing some sort of KBKDF or PBKDF and a decent encryption mechanism is sufficient.

What you do is simple and clear: You look at your chunk of data and extract derivation paramters from it (they are *associated data*), then you ask the user for the file name and completely parse it into your PBKDF / KBKDF of choice. From this you derive an encryption key and a nonce / IV and you're good to go to apply authenticated encryption on your data

You should use a *password based key derivation function* (PBKDF such as [Argon2](https://password-hashing.net/), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) or [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)) if you suspect the file to be low entropy (less than $2^{128}$ plausible possibilities) and use a *key based key derivation function* (KBKDF such as [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) or [KDF2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15673/23623)) in all the other cases. For the actual encryption AES-[EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) is your mode of choice for files that get larger than 60GB and AES-[GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) for anything smaller.

Comment: I'm open for a better standard link for KDF2.