# Secret key out of sha-512

Tags: symmetric, sha-512

This is a setup to produce a secret key for symmetrical encryption with TweetNaCl:

1) K1 consists of 32 random bytes

2) K2 consists of 32 random bytes

(By "random" I mean "obtained from /dev/urandom")

3) KC is the concatenation of K1 and K2

4) K consists of the first 32 bytes of the SHA-512 sum of KC

Questions:

a) Is it safe to use K as a secret key? ("safe" meaning "as safe as using 32 random bytes"; it is assumed that K1, K2 and K are kept secret)

b) If an attacker gets his hands on K1 or K2 (but not on both), does he obtain any real advantage?

Rationale: keep K1 and K2 in separate media (e.g., K1 on a pen and K2 on disk)

Comment: For two random keys you could just XOR them together as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) Is it safe to use K as a secret key? ("safe" meaning "as safe as using 32 random bytes"; it is assumed that K1, K2 and K are kept secret)

Although SHA-512 is not a KDF, and although it is required that the hash has properties that are not mandatory to be used as KDF, most people assume it is secure, yes.

> b) If an attacker gets his hands on K1 or K2 (but not on both), does he obtain any real advantage?

No, the attacker shouldn't gain advantage that way.

---

Kind of related is the security of [KDF1 and KDF2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15673/1172). Hash should be considered a poor mans KDF. For a better KDF, use [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) or just HKDF-expand.

Comment: My reasoning is that there is no point in using HKDF,...,Argon2 when the source (K1 and K2) is random, as opposed to a lower-entropy source (passphrase). Rather than trying a brute-force attack against K1|K2, an attacker might as well try to find the key K itself. That is, assuming that the algorithm used to buid K doesn't introduce some subtle vulnerability.

Comment: There's no point in using SHA-512 either. Just XOR the two keys together as @MaartenBodewes suggests in an earlier comment.

Comment: I'm ashamed to say that I went for the answer and missed the comment entirely.  That looks indeed a better strategy (and makes a leaner binary, too).